# How to import videos/pictures/documents from my Samsung smartphone to my Linux system?

Tags: fedora, files, gnome3, android, file-transfer

I imported most of last year's videos and pictures from my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 to my Fedora 20 laptop through Gwenview import.

Now I want to import the last month's but I'm having difficulty importing, I have quite a few Linux systems and one Windows 7......

Last time, when importing to my laptop, it broke the connector on my phone, had to have it repaired. And it only went through with repeated tries, it always gave errors and I retried as many times as it took for importing all the media....

Now I tried both Gwenview and Shotwell on a different computer, again errors, hanging and Shotwell crashes.

I've managed to import with Gnome on my laptop, but only the images in the folder currently in use by the camera, I have other folders I want to import but Gnome's Shotwell can't do that for some reason.

**Questions:**

Is importing these kind of files from a smartphone's to Linux systems a lost battle?

Is there some better way to import efficiently?

How do I import with Gwenview in Gnome on a Fedora 21?

Comment: I used the copy_to option in Gwenview to import the remaining data, but my question still stands as I would like to know if there is something out there that can do the job of importing from my phone without much hassle.

Comment: Why don't you just mount it like a normal drive and copy the files? Why use a special program?

Comment: @terdon OK. Thats a method.

Answer (score -2):

I use the [AndFTP](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andftp/) application. You can use also `adb pull /dir/dir/your_file`.

Comment: you can use airdroid application too